# Sneaker Sole Replacement

Tags: footwear, repairs

For the last 4 years or so, my day to day walking/hiking shoes have been a pair of Tevas that I picked up from REI ([Riva Event Model: 4103](http://www.teva.com/men-shoes/riva-event/4103.html?dwvar_4103_color=CHRR#q=vibram&start=1&cgid=)). I'm on my second pair now and they've both lasted about 2 years and both have failed in the same way: the sole gets worn out that the water resistant aspects have become a distant memories.

I've enjoyed these shoes and will replace if necessary, but if possible I'd like to defray the monetary and environmental costs by just repairing them. Is it practical to replace the sole of these shoes and if so, will I need to get a cobbler involved or can it be done at home?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it practical to replace the sole of these shoes and if so, will I
>   need to get a cobbler involved or can it be done at home?

Yes, resoling boots is practical and cost effective way to repair boots. I've done it in the past.

You can do it yourself, but I've never tried. Any good cobbler should offer this service or their are specialists on the net that specialise in repairing hiking boots.

Comment: I am not sure this is true, I would like to see some references.  I get boots resoled all the time.  It runs about $70 per pair, but I have only done it with soles that are sewn on.  The example image has glued on soles.  ...BUT... I also know someone who has lifts added to one sole of pair, and they do split soles similar to image in the question, and glue spacers between the sole and shoe, which could also work to add a new sole.  This is medical device procedure and cost is about the same as a new pair of the same shoes in the question,not sure if a cobbler would do this or only orthopedic

Comment: TBH, when I click on the link I don't see the boot. I guessed it was a standard hiking boot which (in my experience) mostly have glued on soles.

Comment: I wouldn't describe these as boots. They're definitely sneakers with a glued on soles, but the soles appear to be clearly separate from the rest of the shoe (hence my problem).  Because it is clearly separate, it seems like I should be able to replace it provided the parts are there and there's a practical method to reattaching it.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical it is possible to resole them with used automobile tires (google it). There are lots of considerations, what is practical to someone who jogs in "BigCity USA" and what is practical in many third world countries varies a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Glued is the least serviceable sole.

A [goodyear welting](http://www.primermagazine.com/2014/spend/understanding-shoe-construction-goodyear-welt-blake-stich-cementing) is designed to be resoled.

Many glued soles can be replaced.  On that sole I don't even think it can be bought from Vibram because of the toe cap. I tried with a similar sole on a pair of Keen and was told no even by Keen.

See [Vibram Sole Factor](https://us.vibram.com/company/education/sole-factor/)

Even with glued models that can be resoled I have found the whole shoe is shot before you wear out the sole and the resole was 1/2 the price of the shoe.

Caro sandals can be resoled but I find them on sale for the price of resole.